# Linux SVN user list

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Linux SVN server for creating and managing SVN repositories. we have multiple repositories and each repostiory has its own set of users and access  permissins. 
Want to know how to find user list and permissions without going into each repository's authz file? Checking each and every repository is a time consuming process and may cause human error. 
Can you suggest me how to list out users and their access ineach repository in one go?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it Apache- or svnserve-based server? Anyway, both can use common shared `authzfile` with all users in it

Comment: Thank you for replying. To add in to the query, we maintain separate authz file for each repostiory. Right now it's svnserve based model. However, we are planning to move onto Apache based model in near futue. But the problem still remains the same. Is there any SVN command/option in tortoise svn where in user and their access list is generated automatically instead of visiting authz file. Thank you.

Comment: you can use shared authz-file even with svnserve and it will be definitely best choice. If it isn't possible and you SVN is 1.8+, you can have ["In repository autz"](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#in-repo-authz) and get it as any other resource from repository (i.e. not by hand), even they are separate files